# JPA or JDBC, how are they different?

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc

I am learning Java EE and I downloaded the eclipse with glassfish for the same. I saw some examples and also read the Oracle docs to know all about Java EE 5. Connecting to a database was very simple. I opened a dynamic web project, created a session EJB ,  I used EntityManager and with the get methods could access the stored data table.

For my next project I had create a simple class and then access some DB table. The very first problem I encountered was that the PersistenceUnit attribute would only be recognized by EJB,Servlet etc and not a simple java class. So then I could not use the EntityManager way(or can I?)

I was asked to go via the "JDBC" way. The very first problem I encountered was to get the connection to the DB. It seems all this must be hardcoded. I had a persistence.xml with which I could easily configure the data base connection. Even setting up a driver for the DB was easy. Also there no get/set methods in the JDBC for accessing table entities.

How do I understand JPA and persistence in relation to JDBC? What was JPA thought for? Why is there set/get methods? Can someone throw some light on the essence of these two and what are the pros/cons without "jargons"?? Please also suggest some links. A simple google search for JPA and JDBC differences led me to some sites full of "terminology" I couldn't follow :(

Comment: Why not start with the JDBC tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Comment: JPA can be used without EJB or even Java EE, you can create an EntityManagerFactory directly from Persistence.

Answer (score 340, accepted):

In layman's terms:

- JDBC is a standard for Database Access
- JPA is a standard for ORM

JDBC is a standard for connecting to a DB directly and running SQL against it - e.g `SELECT * FROM USERS`, etc.  Data sets can be returned which you can handle in your app, and you can do all the usual things like `INSERT`, `DELETE`, run stored procedures, etc.  It is one of the underlying technologies behind most Java database access (including JPA providers).

One of the issues with traditional JDBC apps is that you can often have some crappy code where lots of mapping between data sets and objects occur, logic is mixed in with SQL, etc.

JPA is a standard for Object Relational Mapping. This is a technology which allows you to map between objects in code and database tables.  This can "hide" the SQL from the developer so that all they deal with are Java classes, and the provider allows you to save them and load them magically.  Mostly, XML mapping files or annotations on getters and setters can be used to tell the JPA provider which fields on your object map to which fields in the DB.  The most famous JPA provider is [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org/), so it's a good place to start for concrete examples.

Other examples include OpenJPA, toplink, etc.

Under the hood, Hibernate and most other providers for JPA write SQL and use JDBC to read and write from and to the DB.

Comment: iBatis (nowadays MyBatis) is not an JPA implementation. If you take a look to it, you will notice that it does have very different concept.

Comment: thanks! My mistake, I thought it implemented JPA, corrected now!

Comment: Not all JPA providers write SQL and use JDBC ... since they may persist to a "different type of datastore" (MongoDB, Neo4j, etc). DataNucleus JPA is one such example

Comment: true DataNucleus.. there are even ones for excel, etc - the original questions was JDBC/JPA so I rightly or wrongly assumed he was interested in relational stores.

Comment: Wikipedia (MyBatis): "Unlike ORM frameworks, MyBatis does not map Java objects to database tables but Java methods to SQL statements."

Answer (score 84):

Main difference between JPA and JDBC is level of abstraction.

JDBC is a low level standard for interaction with databases. JPA is higher level standard for the same purpose. JPA allows you to use an object model in your application which can make your life much easier. JDBC allows you to do more things with the Database directly, but it requires more attention. Some tasks can not be solved efficiently using JPA, but may be solved more efficiently with JDBC.

Answer (score 27):

JDBC is a much lower-level (and older) specification than JPA. In it's bare essentials, JDBC is an API for interacting with a database using pure SQL - sending queries and retrieving results. It has no notion of objects or hierarchies. When using JDBC, it's up to you to translate a result set (essentially a row/column matrix of values from one or more database tables, returned by your SQL query) into Java objects.

Now, to understand and use JDBC it's essential that you have some understanding and working knowledge of SQL. With that also comes a required insight into what a relational database is, how you work with it and concepts such as tables, columns, keys and relationships. Unless you have at least a basic understanding of databases, SQL and data modelling you will not be able to make much use of JDBC since it's really only a thin abstraction on top of these things.

Answer (score 15):

JDBC is the predecessor of JPA.

JDBC is a bridge between the Java world and the databases world. In JDBC you need to expose all dirty details needed for CRUD operations, such as table names, column names, while in JPA (which is using JDBC underneath), you also specify those details of database metadata, but with the use of Java annotations.

So JPA creates update queries for you and manages the entities that you looked up or created/updated (it does more as well).

If you want to do JPA without a Java EE container, then Spring and its libraries may be used with the very same Java annotations.

Comment: "without a Java EE container??" Do you mean Spring and its libraries is independent of  web container?

Comment: @BruceZu Of course it is. You can use many of the Spring framework components with no need of a web container. Dependency injection, for example, is not something you need only on a web context.

Comment: @Dolfiz isn't the spring web libraries a wrapper over the Java Web and Java EE libraries?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between JPA and JDBC is often the deciding factor, as the two database technologies take very different approaches to work with persistent data. JDBC, allows developers to construct database-driven Java programs utilizing object-oriented semantics

JPA is database-agnostic, meaning that the same code can be used in a variety of databases with few modifications. JPA serves as a layer of abstraction that hides the low-level JDBC calls from the developer, making database coding considerably easier

hibernate is implementation of JPA
[hibernate](https://hibernate.org/) you can see further details from here about jpa Query

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is a layer of abstraction on top of vendor-specific relational DB drivers. Without JDBC you would have to deal with peculiarities of a specific DB (not much fun). JDBC, however, is too low-level and entails a lot of boilerplate code.

JPA is a specification of an ORM (just an interface). It's useless without an implementation.

ORM is a kind of framework concerned with saving and retrieving objects to/from the relational DB. There are many ORMs out there with different levels of abstraction. Some of them require manually-written SQL.

*Some* of ORMs implement JPA (Hibernate or EclipseLink, for example). *Most* of them are built on top of JDBC.

Such ORMs provide the maximum level of abstraction to the point you almost never have to write SQL queries. Some people love JPA-based ORMs (they reduce boilerplate), some hate (abstraction is leaky, specification is overly complex and there are lots of corner cases).

Java analogy:

```
class ORM extends JDBC implements JPA {
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Persistence layers have protocols versions so abstractions also have versions therefore you need ranges of supported versions. It is version hell