# Vaadin: What is the point of a H2 database?

Tags: vaadin, h2, jpacontainer

The `JPAcontainer` tutorial here: https://vaadin.com/download/jpacontainer-tutorial/

Indicates that you need a `H2` database driver with `JPAcontainer`. I don't understand why? - what functionality do you loose from not having `H2` as well as `JPAcontainer`?

Answer (score 5):

For the record:

- H2 is a database that is slim and can be run as server or embedded in your Java application (in-memory). It provides a JDBC driver.
- JPA is a Java API that provides an interface for object relational
  mapping (ORM). Implementations, e.g.:

  - Hibernate
  - EclipseLink

Vaadin's `JPAContainer` is independent from the database and JPA implementation you deploy. It is built upon JPA to implement the Vaadin `Container` interface. It is somewhat similar to the `SQLContainer` but uses JPA instead of plain SQLs.

However, you need a database and its JDBC driver to make use of the `JPAContainer`. Your linked tutorial takes H2 for that, probably because H2 is open source, free and simple.

That said, you can safely replace H2 with your favorite database.

Comment: Similar comment with some additional details on a slighlty different question: [jpa or jdbc - how are they different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881548/jpa-or-jdbc-how-are-they-different). Nonetheless you pretty much summed it all up, +1